# Map network drive to cloud storage?

Tags: networking, sync, dropbox

My company currently shares local documents using a network drive.  Every Friday, I have to send a specific set of these local files to another branch of the company in a different city.

Is there a way to automatically sync all the local documents to a cloud storage, so that I do not have to manually send the files each Friday?

For example, is there a way to automatically sync all the network drive files to a DropBox folder in realtime?

Thanks

Comment: Dropbox cannot be mounted as network drive, but you could look into online storage services which do support WebDAV protocol.

Comment: Not "realtime" at least not that I am aware of. You can use something like SyncBack that can do sync (2-way sync) or backup (1-way copying) from a remote (network) location, to a dropbox folder (assuming you install dropbox, and dropbox created a folder on your computer). And you can schedule SyncBack to run on certain time as well using windows built-in task Scheduler. (Note: These are windows solution, if you have different OS, then these may not apply)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to automatically sync all the local documents to a
>   cloud storage, so that I do not have to manually send the files each
>   Friday?

I think so. There is a way to automatically sync all the local documents to cloud storage. If you install Dropbox application on all computers, you can use [Selective Sync feature](https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en) to synchronize your selected files or simply use Dropbox folder to sync all documents. Of course you need to add your local documents which you want to synchronize to Dropbox folder .

If you don't want to copy the files to a Dropbox folder every Friday, you may want to create [scheduled tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/schedule-a-task) or use a batch script for it (I don't know which OS you are using. If it is not Windows, please check Linux or Macs job's or task solutions).

There are many ways to synchronize your documents. Please check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Synchronize-Folders) or Google Drive solutions.