# Replacing local server and network drives with a cloud storage equivalent

Tags: network-shares, cloud-storage, network-drive

In our business, we have a local server and all devices on the network can access any of the drives in this server but we're very serious in wanting to move to a cloud-based solution so that we don't have to keep replacing hard disks every x years and backing up/moving data all the time.

Typically, in Windows for example, under 'This PC' you'd have all the network drives available for different areas of our business so it's easily accessible by navigation (and on Mac's and Ubuntu, their own similar equivalents) - this is essentially what I am wanting to do with cloud storage.

So basically, in the cloud, have various folders and then be able to map network drives directly to these folders in the cloud across all our devices (or something very similar to this) so we would need any device on our network to just automatically pick up these network locations ideally without manual intervention on everyone's device (although absolutely fine if we can just send a bash script to run on startup or something). And of course, ensure this is all secure or maybe even encrypted etc.

I know there are lots of cloud storage products on the market, we've even used many of them and have explored some of them previously. But almost all of them put their main focus on syncing data between the cloud and your device (think Dropbox, Google Drive and OneDrive for example) and that is not important in what I am searching for here.

I can see the same or very similar questions have been asked on here before ([example 1](https://superuser.com/questions/743463/cloud-storage-map-to-network-drive), [example 2](https://superuser.com/questions/682914/map-network-drive-to-cloud-storage), [example 3](https://superuser.com/questions/1224079/make-mapped-network-drive-appear-as-local-drive)) but I'm really wanting some more in-depth suggestions to what my options to actually achieve what I am seeking.

We don't want to be having to mess around sync-selecting on a per-device level which would be the issue with the likes of **Google Drive** (which we already use heavily in our business), **Dropbox for Business** (we used to use but dropped them due to significant performance issues) or **Microsoft OneDrive**.

In an ideal world, as our business is already set up in Google Workspace with Google Drive and Google Storage, it would be ideal to have a Google Cloud Storage set up for this but this just seems to be tied into Google Drive - **is there any difference between Google Cloud Storage and Google Drive**? (I'm sure there is much more flexibility in working with Google Cloud Storage). I mean, Google Storage/Drive is fine for the actual storage but then we just have the problems of having to look after what syncs where.

#### Storage Requirement

I should probably note at this stage, the storage we're after would be probably between 5Tb - 10Tb and of course scalable - (and quite a few million files and folders).

### Service Options

Some of the solutions I've been having a look at this week include:-

[image: Drives Appearance in Windows 10]

#### pCloud

✅ Creates a local drive with the capacity of storage you have paid for in your plan.

❌ Local drives won't show up as a network location.

❌ Doesn't have the ability to set up more than one drive pointing to different locations in their cloud.

#### Egnyte

✅ Creates a network drive with the capacity of storage you have paid for in your plan.

✅ Shows up as a network location so all other devices will see this on the network (presumably).

✅ I have managed to create different folders under the account's 'Shared' path and can map different drives custom labelled to any of these (excellent!).

❌ Looks like their subscription plan model will end up resulting in every device that requires access acting as a 'user'.

#### Icedrive

✅ Creates a network drive with the capacity of storage you have paid for in your plan.

❌ Local drives won't show up as a network location.

❌ Doesn't have the ability to set up more than one drive pointing to different locations in their cloud.

#### RaiDrive

✅ Creates a network drive with the capacity of storage you have paid for in your plan.

✅ Shows up as a network location so all other devices will see this on the network (presumably).

✅ Allows you to set up drives connecting via WebDAV, SFTP, and others so there is this flexibility in this sense but unsure if one of these is the best option for mapping to space in the cloud or not.

❌ Doesn't appear that I have any flexibility in pointing custom drives to different folders within the same cloud space (for example, different folders within the same Google Drive account).

#### Others Options?

We are already familiar with Google Drive, Dropbox, Microsoft OneDrive, iDrive but none of these (as standalone) seem suitable for working with over multiple drives to multiple paths.

I've been trying to search for the best app for what I am after on sites like [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/) but it's difficult to get the right categories and only include the necessary features so you end up with irrelevant alternatives like FTP clients and web hosting companies.

I'm also aware of software that will also provide you with greater flexibility in mapping locations on a device to external sources in the cloud such as **Mountain Duck** which I will also consider should it be needed on top of a cloud storage provider.

If it is possible to achieve, I also will consider setting up our own cloud server (if there is even an affordable option for this much storage space) and mapping drives to folders on this.

### Pricing

I'm ideally hoping for a solution where we are just paying for the actual storage that we need (and not at stupendous prices) - Google's pricing for it's storage is fine for us but if we're talking £hundreds per month for 5+ Tb, then it's not financially viable as would cost significantly more than our local on-premises server set up.

We want to avoid a pricing model per user or device because that just doesn't fit what we're trying to do - we don't need any features other than to access folders in the cloud from any part of our network.

---

### Clarification

My question here is not really to ask for product recommendations but more-so for any ways I can achieve what it is I am after. If I know what can do what it is I am after, then I can go off and explore those options instead of spending months of testing everything I come across.

Please leave me a comment if you want me to elaborate on any specifics that will help you answer.

Comment: Sorry  despite your assertion, this is really a product revommendation question).

Comment: @davidgo I don't know how to achieve what I am after - I want to know of any products that can singularly do it or a combination of products that can do it. I was trying to avoid getting recommended a load of products that can't even do what it is I am attempting.

Comment: Im not particularly motivated by cloud stuff so dont know the details or practicality  but you may want to look at Amazons S3 service (and/or glacier depending on your rrtention requirements). zI **think** s3 can be used directly via Smb and/or NFS  and there are fuse filesystems as well - so if you have good enough network connectivity that may be the answer. If-course  reluable cloud will typically  cost more the on-prem solution if you ignore your time.

Comment: Have you ascertained you have the bandwidth to even make it viable?

Comment: @davidgo - thanks, I'm having a look at https://aws.amazon.com/s3/glacier/. I have no idea if our company can support the bandwidth but typically this will not be heavy transferring of files between cloud and device - and also device access to cloud will be from different locations (remote staff etc).

Answer (score 0):

The Newest Windows server integrates with Azure Cloud. Just to put it on the table.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/.

"Take advantage of fully managed file shares in the cloud that are accessible via the industry-standard SMB and NFS protocols. Azure file shares can be mounted concurrently by cloud or on-premises deployments of Windows, Linux, and macOS."

I have in the past used a product called own-cloud which you could install on a vps type solution, it has a dropbox style interface.